# ArangoDB INTERSECTION() with repetition

Tags: intersection, arangodb

I've found myself in a scenario where I need to find the intersection of two arrays in order to be able to count the number of times that an item is occurring in the intersection. Unfortunately, ArangoDB's INTERSECTION() tool removes duplicates. Anyone know of a way to preserve repetitions without using a filter? Here's what I'm currently working with.

```
FOR x in INTERSECTION ((
for v IN 2 ANY a1 GRAPH 'Graph1'
    COLLECT eid = v._id WITH COUNT into groups
    RETURN {"eid" : eid, "count" : groups }),(
for v IN 2 ANY a2 GRAPH 'Graph2'
    COLLECT eid = v._id WITH COUNT into groups
    RETURN {"eid" : eid, "count" : groups }))
SORT x.count DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN x
```

Another issue (that might be the root of the problem) is that I need the intersection to take place only with eid and it is currently comparing both eid and count. Meaning that if eid/5 occurs 10 times in the first set but 8 times in the second set, it is ignored. However, if I do the count after the intersection, all items return with a count of 1 because the duplicates were removed. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't store the sub-query results in variables to use use them twice? Like `LET q1 = (FOR v IN 2 ANY a1 ...)` and `LET q2 = (FOR v IN 2 ANY a2 ...)`, then `FOR x IN INTERSECTION( UNIQUE(q1), UNIQUE(q2) ) ...`? However, the use of `UNIQUE()` should be unnecessary. Or I don't understand what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this AQL and it should work:

```
LET arA = (
for v IN 2 ANY a1 GRAPH 'Graph1'
    COLLECT eid = v._id WITH COUNT into groups
    RETURN {"eid" : eid, "count" : groups })
LET arB = (
for v IN 2 ANY a2 GRAPH 'Graph2'
    COLLECT eid = v._id WITH COUNT into groups
    RETURN {"eid" : eid, "count" : groups })
LET x = (FOR x in INTERSECTION (arA[*].eid,arB[*].eid)
 RETURN x)
FOR final IN UNION(arA,arB)
  FILTER final.eid IN x 
  SORT final.count DESC
RETURN final
```

basically the arrays are counted separately, then you do the INTERSECTION, to get the EIDs, which are in both arrays.

But then, separately, using UNION, iterate through all items again, filtering only these, which are in INTERSECTION and sort them by the attribute f.count. The count attribute is now available, because I have entries from both original array, which are filtered by eid presented in INTERSECTION.

And the results are:

```
[
  {
    "eid": "eid6",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "eid": "eid3",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "eid": "eid2",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "eid": "eid3",
    "count": 3
  }
]
```